# PL/SQL check time period, repeat, up until 600 records, from large database

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

What would be the best way to check if there has been data within a 3 month period up until a maximum of 600 records, then repeat for the 3 months before that if 600 hasn't been reached? Also it's a large table so querying the whole thing could take a few minutes or completely hang Oracle SQL Developer.

ROWNUM seems to give row numbers to the whole table before returning the result of the query, so that seems to take too long. The way we are currently doing it is entering a time period explicitly that we guess there will be enough records within and then limiting the rows to 600. This only takes 5 seconds, but needs to be changed constantly.

I was thinking to do a FOR loop through each row, but am having trouble storing the number of results outside of the query itself to check whether or not 600 has been reached.

I was also thinking about creating a data index? But I don't know much about that. Is there a way to sort the data by date before grabbing the whole table that would be faster?

Thank you

Comment: Please, provide sample structures with sample data **in text format or as insert statements** and desired output for this sample data. Sample also means, that 600 may be replaced with, for example, 4. It is hard to tell what to do with unknown abstract structures

Comment: 3 questions that could shed some light:

1) What happens if you try this?
    `ORDER BY your_date_field DESC FETCH FIRST 600 ROWS ONLY` 
2) How long does it take to COUNT(*) the entire table?
3) Do you know if there's an index on that date field already?

The fact that it takes 5 secs if date is specified in the WHERE could suggest the field is indexed and/or the actual problem is how long the larger datasets take to travel back to your client over network (not how long the db takes to run your query).
Also, if possible, try selecting only fields you need, and don't do SELECT *

Comment: There are ways to do what you asked in PL/SQL, but without knowing the answers to the questions from my other comment, there's a decent chance those solutions would result in querying your table multiple times and make it take longer than a simpler SQL solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> check if there has been data within a 3 month period up until a maximum of 600 records, then repeat for the 3 months before that if 600 hasn't been reached?

Find the latest date and filter to only allow the rows that are within 6 months of it and then fetch the first 600 rows:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         MAX(date_column) OVER () AS max_date_column
  FROM   table_name t
)
WHERE  date_column > ADD_MONTHS( max_date_column, -6 )
ORDER BY date_column DESC
FETCH FIRST 600 ROWS ONLY;
```

If there are 600 or more within the latest 3 months then they will be returned; otherwise it will extend the result set into the next 3 month period.

---

If you intend to repeat the extension over more than two 3-month periods then just use:

```
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
ORDER BY date_column DESC
FETCH FIRST 600 ROWS ONLY;
```

---

> I was also thinking about creating a data index? But I don't know much about that. Is there a way to sort the data by date before grabbing the whole table that would be faster?

Yes, creating an index on the date column would, typically, make filtering the table faster.